# Xcode 6.3 "incoming connections..." popup

Tags: xcode, popup, certificate, xcode6.3

I have recently update Xcode to 6.3.  Ever since the update, I started seeing a popup asking to accept or deny incoming connections the Xcode on a standard user account on the same machine even though I have Xcode listed in Firewall preferences panel.

I did some research and find something points to certification issue.  I just remove Xcode and is now in the process of reinstalling.

Is it just me or does other people have the same issue?  Any thought of how to get rid of the popup?

Comment: after reinstalled Xcode, the popup seems to have gone away.